# How to parse from one column to create another with Pandas and Regex?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pd dataframe with one column `user_id` and each row ends with "/tgroup..."

I want to create a new column `group_id` where each row will have the corresponding "tgroup..." matching `user_id`.

This is my implementation so far:

```
                                         user_id
0  87dce49a-f752-47f8-9bc4-b97a446a85f5\tgroup-0
1  87dce49a-f752-47f8-9bc4-b97a446a85f5\tgroup-1
2  87dce49a-f752-47f8-9bc4-b97a446a85f5\tgroup-2
3  87dce49a-f752-47f8-9bc4-b97a446a85f5\tgroup-3
4  87dce49a-f752-47f8-9bc4-b97a446a85f5\tgroup-4


df['group_id'] = df['user_id'].apply(lambda x: re.findall('(^\t)',x))

print(df.head())

                                         user_id group_id
0  87dce49a-f752-47f8-9bc4-b97a446a85f5\tgroup-0       []
1  87dce49a-f752-47f8-9bc4-b97a446a85f5\tgroup-1       []
2  87dce49a-f752-47f8-9bc4-b97a446a85f5\tgroup-2       []
3  87dce49a-f752-47f8-9bc4-b97a446a85f5\tgroup-3       []
4  87dce49a-f752-47f8-9bc4-b97a446a85f5\tgroup-4       []
```

Clearly lambda/regex method is not grabbing the string selection that I want.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is `\t` the tab character or backslash and `t`? If the latter you can try:

```
df['group_id'] = df.user_id.str.extract(r'\\t(.*)')
```

Output:

```
                                         user_id group_id
0  87dce49a-f752-47f8-9bc4-b97a446a85f5\tgroup-0  group-0
1  87dce49a-f752-47f8-9bc4-b97a446a85f5\tgroup-1  group-1
2  87dce49a-f752-47f8-9bc4-b97a446a85f5\tgroup-2  group-2
3  87dce49a-f752-47f8-9bc4-b97a446a85f5\tgroup-3  group-3
4  87dce49a-f752-47f8-9bc4-b97a446a85f5\tgroup-4  group-4
```

Comment: I only get NaN values under group_id when I use this method

Comment: Check again with `r'\t(.*)'`, where `\t` denotes the tab character.

Comment: That works! How would I go about then removing the `\t...` from each row in `user_id`?

Comment: `df.user_id.str.replace('\t', '')`